# Rhino Javascript JSON object

Tags: rhino

I use java to call the Rhino javascript, and it works.

in the javascript file, I define the following javascript object

```
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
```

then trying to access object by:

```
print(JSON.stringify(person))
```

and I got a error  **has no public instance field or method named "toJSON".**

I am confused, the way the person gets defined it is definitly a JS object. how come this runtime thinks its still a Java object

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at issue in the [Rhino GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/issues/182) , also linking [PR that still open](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/pull/12)

Comment: is this fixed in the latest release in 2018?